# What is the minimum size of a partial order containing all partial orders of size 5?

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, posets, computer-algebra

[This earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25874/what-is-the-minimal-size-of-a-partial-order-that-is-universal-for-all-partial-or) asks to find the minimum size of a partial order that is universal for all partial orders of size $n$, i.e. any partial order of size $n$ embeds into it, preserving the order. In particular, the question asks if the minimum size $f(n)$ has a polynomial upper bound, to which the answer is no.

In this question, I am interested in some concrete values of $f(n)$ for small $n$.
So far, I know that:

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(2) = 3$
- $f(3) = 5$
- $f(4) = 8$
- $f(n) \ge 2n - 1$
- $f(n) \in \Omega(n^k)$ for all $k$

Can we compute some additional values in this sequence? In particular, can we compute $f(5)$?

#### Notes

- I was able to verify $f(4) = 8$ [using a computer-assisted proof using a SAT solver](https://github.com/cdstanford/curiosities/blob/master/universal-poset/universal-poset.als). I also tried naive enumeration of posets and checking for universality, but this fails at around $f(4)$. Computing $f(5)$ may require smarter enumeration, in particular better symmetry breaking.
- The sequence does not appear to be in OEIS yet (it does not appear to be any of the sequences beginning with 1, 3, 5, 8). I submitted [this draft](https://oeis.org/draft/A337981), and it was suggested that the sequence should be posted to MathOverflow to find more terms.

**EDIT:** New OEIS entry with f(5) = 11 [here](https://oeis.org/A340318).

Comment: Is there a database of small posets? It [looks like](http://oeis.org/A000112) you could brute-force search sizes up to 11 if you had such a database.

Comment: @AndrejBauer http://oeis.org/A000798/a000798_6.pdf has an illustration of the 318 6-posets. The first 63 of these are in effect the 5-posets if you ignore the left-hand isolated element

Comment: I can generate the 6-posets very easily myself, but sizes up to 11 seem like more of a challenge. Do you know if those are avialable anywhere?

Comment: This may be useful: [Posets on up to 16 points](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/posets.pdf). I haven't found a list of them yet.

Comment: If someone wants to do some programming, I can provide posets. Up to 11 points I can give you a gzipped file of about 140 MB.  12 points takes 3.1 GB which is more than my web server has free at the moment, but I could provide the generator program in C (you will need the 'nauty' package to compile it).

Comment: "This draft" link leads to a different sequence.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev The sequence was recycled due to not having enough terms. It could be re-proposed now that we have f(5).

Comment: @6005: I this it's a good idea.

Comment: Cool. I have proposed it again at https://oeis.org/draft/A340318

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Can you please provide the 318 6-posets?

Comment: OEIS Sequence [now published](https://oeis.org/A340318)! Thanks everyone for the effort here!

Comment: @RobPratt  http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/digraphs.html

Comment: The recent preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.01764.pdf gives a much more precise asymptotic (see Corollary 1.9). It was posted in answer to the linked question. Should this be included in the OEIS page?

Comment: @WillSawin I think editing to include it is a great idea.

Comment: The name of the preprint @WillSawin [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375031/what-is-the-minimum-size-of-a-partial-order-containing-all-partial-orders-of-siz/380561#comment966650_375031):  [Bonamy, Esperet, Groenland, and Scott - Optimal labelling schemes for adjacency,comparability and reachability](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.01764).

Answer (score 18):

(Edited several times from earlier partial answer, which gave $f(5) \ge 11$.)

We have exact results $f(5) = 11$ and $f(6)=16$, and bounds $16 \le f(7) \le 25$.

### 1. Proving $f(5)=11$

A short proof shows that $f(5) \ge 10$. To be 5-universal (*i.e.* contain isomorphic copies of all partial orders of 5 elements), our poset must contain a 5-chain. Also it must contain two incomparable 2-chains, only one of which could overlap the 5-chain. Also it must contain 5 incomparable elements (only two of which could be in the previous chains). So at least 5+2+1+1+1 = 10 elements. I believe this is essentially the kind of lower-bound argument that was mentioned in the [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25874/what-is-the-minimal-size-of-a-partial-order-that-is-universal-for-all-partial-or). This "multiple chains" argument says nothing about branching structures in the 5-posets, so perhaps one could consider them and work out an improved lower bound.

A really brute-force SageMath code (see below) tries all 10-posets (about 2.6 million) in about 15 hours, and finds no 5-universal posets, so this proves $f(5) \ge 11$.

Although the code is pretty slow, luckily with 11-posets it finds a solution in just 22 hours, having tried 1.0% of all approx. [47 million](https://oeis.org/A000112/list) 11-posets. The 11-poset with cover relation
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 4], [1, 9], [2, 5], [2, 7], [2, 8],
[3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [5, 10], [7, 10],
[8, 10], [9, 10]]
is 5-universal so we have $f(5) \le 11$.

[image: A 5-universal 11-poset]

```
# Find a u-poset that contains all n-posets as induced subposets.
def find_universal_poset(n,u):
    PP = list(Posets(n))
    for U in Posets(u):
        ok = True
        for P in PP:
            if not U.has_isomorphic_subposet(P):
                ok = False
                break
        if ok:
            return U
    return None
```

### 2. Proving $f(6)=16$

For $f(6)$ the SageMath code is too slow. We can do faster brute-force in two phases: (1) list the candidate posets using "posets.c" by Brinkmann & McKay, available in an old SageMath [enhancement request](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14110), and (2) check them for 6-universality by C code corresponding to the SageMath code listed above.

The multiple-chains argument gives easily $f(6) \ge 14$, because a 6-universal poset must contain a 6-chain, two mutually incomparable 3-chains, three such 2-chains, and six incomparable elements; these can overlap but at least 6+3+2+1+1+1=14 elements are required.

I have ruled out $f(6)=14$ by exhaustive search over all $1.34 \times 10^{12}$ 14-posets (about 16 cpu-days of computation), and ruled out $f(6)=15$ similarly (about 1200 cpu-days). The result rests on heavy computation, so it would be nice to have a more succint lower bound proof, perhaps from a more elaborate version of the multiple-chains argument.

Exhaustive search over all 16-posets would take about 500 cpu-years, but some solutions were found after just 190 cpu-hours, that is, having done about 1/20000 of the search space. (There must be quite a lot of 6-universal 16-posets out there, to explain this luck.) One of the solutions has cover relation
[[2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0], [4, 1], [5, 0], [5, 1], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 2], [8, 3], [8, 4], [8, 6], [8, 7], [9, 6], [9, 7], [10, 6], [11, 9], [11, 10], [12, 2], [12, 3], [12, 10], [13, 9], [13, 12], [14, 5], [14, 7], [14, 12], [15, 11], [15, 13], [15, 14]].
So we have $f(6) = 16$.

[image: A 6-universal 16-poset]

Another computational approach for upper bounds is to start from a known 6-universal poset, such as the Boolean lattice $B_6$ (= power set with inclusion relation), and *remove elements one by one*, if possible without breaking the universality. The idea of removing some unneeded elements is already implicit in the [old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25874/what-is-the-minimal-size-of-a-partial-order-that-is-universal-for-all-partial-or). This is potentially much faster than brute-force for finding positive examples -- if they exist! Not knowing any better, I removed elements in random order until impossible, and restarted 100 times. Already here I got **one 17-poset** and seventeen 18-posets. This 6-universal 17-poset has cover relation
[[0, 11], [0, 13], [0, 15], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 8], [2, 11], [3, 11], [3, 12], [4, 5], [4, 10], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 9], [6, 11], [6, 14], [7, 8], [7, 12], [8, 9], [8, 13], [9, 16], [10, 11], [10, 12], [10, 15], [11, 16], [12, 13], [12, 14], [13, 16], [14, 16], [15, 16]].

```
def is_universal_poset(n, U):
    return all(U.has_isomorphic_subposet(P) for P in Posets(n))

def reduce_universal(n, P):
    print(P)
    if not is_universal_poset(n, P):
        return None    # Already nonuniversal
    R = list(Permutations(P).random_element())
    for r in R:
        Pr = P.subposet(set(P).difference(set([r])))
        if is_universal_poset(n, Pr):
            return reduce_universal(n, Pr)    # Try removing more
    return P        # Could not remove any element
```

### 3. Bounds for $f(7)$

Brute-force is pretty much out of question (AFAIK nobody has listed all nonisomorphic 17-posets). For some loose bounds:

The multiple-chains argument gives $f(7) \ge 16$, because you need one 7-chain, two 3-chains, three 2-chains and seven incomparable elements, 7+3+2+1+1+1+1=16.

Removing random elements from $B_7$, we find easily (in less than ten random restarts) an example of a 7-universal 25-poset, with cover relation
[[0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 14], [1, 2], [1, 5], [2,
6], [2, 11], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 8], [3, 14], [4, 7], [4, 18], [5, 6],
[5, 7], [5, 12], [6, 9], [6, 13], [6, 19], [7, 22], [7, 23], [8, 9],
[9, 15], [9, 23], [10, 11], [10, 12], [10, 14], [11, 13], [11, 15],
[11, 20], [12, 13], [12, 15], [12, 16], [12, 20], [13, 21], [14, 15],
[14, 16], [15, 22], [16, 24], [17, 18], [18, 19], [19, 20], [19, 23],
[20, 21], [20, 22], [21, 24], [22, 24], [23, 24]].
So we have $f(7) \le 25$. This might be improved by trying more random restarts, perhaps with faster C code. I'm not planning to do that now, but it should be straightforward.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the partial answer.

Comment: I have proposed the sequence again, this time with f(5) = 11 at https://oeis.org/draft/A340318

Comment: If I understand correctly, here is another 5-universal poset on 11 elements, found via integer linear programming rather than explicit enumeration: $$(0, 1), (3, 2), (4, 5), (7, 6), (9, 5), (2, 1), (2, 10), (8, 5), (7, 4), (1, 8), (3, 9), (1, 6), (0, 4), (3, 7), (7, 8), (6, 5)$$

Comment: @RobPratt: Certainly there can be more than one n-universal poset of the minimum size, but is the one you present 5-universal? I think it lacks the induced 5-subposet with the cover relation {(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(4,5)}, i.e. a 3-chain and a 2-chain which are incomparable to each other. At least I understood the original question as requiring induced subposets (= the subset inherits the order from the big poset), perhaps the original poster can clarify this point.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen The relation you listed uses 6 elements.

Comment: Sorry - I meant {(0,1),(1,2),(3,4)}. I.e. three elements in one chain and two elements in another.

Comment: Yes, that is missing.  I had a data error in the input and will rerun.

Comment: OEIS Sequence [now published](https://oeis.org/A340318)! Thanks everyone for the effort here! I am looking forward to seeing more terms as well.

Comment: Corrected 5-universal 11-poset from integer linear programming: $$(0, 5), (1, 6), (1, 9), (2, 10), (3, 6), (3, 9), (4, 6), (4, 10), (5, 8), (6, 8), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (9, 5), (9, 10)$$

Comment: Very nice! $f(6)$ may be barely within reach of brute force
search. The elementary "multiple chains" argument says $f(6) \ge
14$ (because one 6-chain, two 3-chains, three 2-chains, six 1-chains
=> 6+3+2+1+1+1). Testing all 14-posets is doable, but unless we are
lucky, we need to test the $6.8 \times 10^{13}$ unlabelled 15-posets,
just listing them will take perhaps 30 cpu days. And if we need the
16-posets it is some cpu-years of computation. Certainly would be better to "build" the universal poset somehow than to search for it in the haystack.

Comment: I'm curious about the integer linear programming approach: does its running time scale better than brute force? Perhaps we could get more terms that way.

Answer (score 7):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $P$ be the set of $n$-posets to be covered, and for $(i,j)\in [n] \times [n]$ let $a_{p,i,j}$ indicate whether $i \preceq j$ in poset $p$.  We want to find a universal $m$-set if possible.  For $(i,j)\in [m] \times [m]$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether $i \preceq j$ in the universal poset.  For $p \in P$, $i_1\in [n]$, and $i_2\in [m]$, let binary decision variable $y_{p,i_1,i_2}$ indicate whether element $i_1$ in poset $p$ is assigned to element $i_2$ in the universal set.
A universal $m$-poset exists if and only if the following constraints can be satisfied:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i_2 \in [m]} y_{p,i_1,i_2} &= 1 
&&\text{for $p\in P$ and $i_1 \in [n]$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{i_1 \in [n]} y_{p,i_1,i_2} &\le 1 
&&\text{for $p \in P$ and $i_2 \in [m]$} \tag2 \\
y_{p,i_1,i_2} + y_{p,j_1,j_2} - 1 &\le x_{i_2,j_2} 
&&\text{for $p\in P, (i_1,j_1) \in [n] \times [n], (i_2, j_2) \in [m] \times [m]$ with $a_{p,i_1,j_1}=1$} \tag3 \\
y_{p,i_1,i_2} + y_{p,j_1,j_2} - 1 &\le 1 - x_{i_2,j_2}
&&\text{for $p\in P, (i_1,j_1) \in [n] \times [n], (i_2, j_2) \in [m] \times [m]$ with $a_{p,i_1,j_1}=0$} \tag4 \\
x_{i,j} + x_{j,k} - 1 &\le x_{i,k}
&&\text{for $i,j,k \in [m]$} \tag5 \\
\\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns each element in poset $p$ to exactly one element in the universal poset.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns at most one element in poset $p$ to each element in the universal poset.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $$(y_{p,i_1,i_2} \land y_{p,j_1,j_2} \land a_{p,i_1,j_1}) \implies x_{i_2,j_2}.$$
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $$(y_{p,i_1,i_2} \land y_{p,j_1,j_2} \land \lnot a_{p,i_1,j_1}) \implies \lnot x_{i_2,j_2}.$$
Constraint $(5)$ enforces transitivity in the universal poset.

Comment: Nice ILP encoding. I wonder if it helps to hard-code some element mappings, e.g. decide beforehand that the elements of the $n$-chain $C_n = \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ are mapped to the same numbers in the universal poset. This might break some symmetries in the solution space, and fix the values of several $x_{i,j}$. Or are ILP solvers nowadays clever enough to work such things out on their own? Come to think of it, one could *also* fix the image of an $n$-antichain.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, in fact, I had done a similar fixing for the antichain, as well as fixing $x_{i,j}=0$ for the corresponding pairs.  Modern commercial solvers do exploit symmetry, but this can still help.

Answer (score 4):

I will try to revive Sagemath's ticket [#14110](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14110) and provide a Sagemath package for this enumeration (in fact, the C code, corresponding to the paper [B. D. McKay and G. Brinkmann, Posets on up to 16 points, Order, 19 (2002) 147-179](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1016543307592) -   (mostly) due to Gunnar Brinkmann, which is using Brendan's McKay's nauty, is posted there.